# Android Provider is not providing the current location

Tags: android, location

I have developed an application in which we send the code from our friends mobile to our mobile.If the code matches with the saved one then it should send the currentlocation of the mobile to friends mobile as an sms. Here is my code

```
     if (message.equals(locatecode)) {
                    // Get the location manager
                    locationManager = (LocationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
                    // Creating an empty criteria object
                    Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
                    // Getting the name of the provider that meets the criteria
                    provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);
                    Toast.makeText(context, provider, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    if (provider != null && !provider.equals("")) {
                        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 0, 0, locListener);
                        Toast.makeText(context,"After requestLocationUp", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        // Get the location from the given provider
                         Location location1 = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
                        Toast.makeText(context, (CharSequence) location1, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                       if(location1!=null) {
                            Toast.makeText(context, "inside location!null",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            int lat = (int) (location1.getLatitude());
                            int lng = (int) (location1.getLongitude());
                            Toast.makeText(context, "latitude:"+String.valueOf(lat),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            Toast.makeText(context, "longitude:"+String.valueOf(lng),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                          try {
                            SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
                            smsManager.sendTextMessage(senderNum, null, m1+"latitude is"+lat+"longitude is"+lng, null, null);
                            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, "SMS sent.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                            toast.show();
                           } catch (Exception e) {
                            Toast.makeText(context, "SMS failed, please try again.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                           }
                       }
                        else
                            Toast.makeText(context, "Location can't be retrieved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                    else {
                        Toast.makeText(context, "No Provider Found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }

                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(context, "not matched", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            } // end for loop
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("SmsReceiver", "Exception smsReceiver" + e);
    }
}

public class myLocationListener implements LocationListener {
    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        if(location!=null) {
            locationManager.removeUpdates(locListener);
            Double latitude = location.getLatitude();
            Double longitude = location.getLongitude();
            System.out.println(latitude + "" + longitude);
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras){      // TODO Auto-generated method stub}
    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String s) {}
    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String s) { }
```

}

```
my problem is it always shows location cannot be retrieved.I have got the same problem in emulator and in phone also.i have given permissions also.So please help me out how to resolve this as soon as possible.
```

Answer (score 0):

LocationManager is a tricky beast. Unfortunately it doesn't return a location in getLastKnownLocation unless some other app happens to have already gotten you a location. You will get location data eventually in your onLocationChanged but you are just printing that out and doing nothing with it. And then you're removing your request for locations so it will only do that once. Consider performing your sms messaging code in the onLocationChanged, and don't removeUpdates or you won't get any updates as you're walking around.

Side note, there is a new and better way to access location data that you really should be using as it's better for battery life: https://developer.android.com/google/play-services/location.html

Comment: i cant implement the sms code inside the onLocationChanged as sms can only be implemented inside broadcastreceiver class. And i call the locationmnager only if the smscode matches with the saved one.can you suggest me anyways how to implement smscode inside onlocationchanged

Comment: Sorry what I meant was this section of code:

Toast.makeText(context, "inside location!null",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            int lat = (int) (location1.getLatitude());
                            int lng = (int) (location1.getLongitude());
                            Toast.makeText(context, "latitude:"+String.valueOf(lat),Toast. ... should be in the onLocationChanged

Comment: Of course with modifications to use the location that occurred in onLocationChanged

Comment: I dint get u. Toast is not working inside onlocationchanged. its showing erron at context i replaced it wth getBaseContext and hetApplicationContext but its not working

Comment: That is because myLocationListener doesn't have a valid ui context. You could pass it in on creation.

Comment: i dont  have oncreate method in that class which extends broadcastreceiver

Comment: Yes that's true,I meant creation of your myLocationListener. You can make a constructor that takes in the context you get in onRecieve. `myLocationListener(Context c) { myContext = c;}`

Comment: it does not work. I tried using service class inside broadcastreceiver class.but the problem is whenever i create an object for service class and try to call that from inside broadcastreceiver class its not working.it does not show any errors but stil the object is not working.So help me out how to create an object of service class from inside broadcastreceiver class.

Comment: CAN  ANYONE HELP ME OUT THIS ASAP

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by service class from inside the broadcastreciever. Perhaps post your new code?

Comment: It is here  in this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28748929/objects-created-for-service-class-inside-broadcastreceiver-class-not-working